# Read java file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some .java files inside a directory, I want to read those files and get some values inside each of them. I'm not sure on how to proceed. how can I do this using fs module and some other npm modules in node js.

Below is my current code

```
const path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports={
    readTS: function () {  

        var CWD = path.join(__dirname, '../');
        var folder = path.basename(CWD).toLowerCase();

        var TSJavaPath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/main/java/com/'+folder+'/');

        var files = fs.readdirSync(TSJavaPath).filter(fn => fn.startsWith('TS'));
        console.log(files);

        for(i=0;i<files;i++){
        //Read and get data
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: What values do you want to get from those files? What do they represent? - Since Java sources are plain text files you have two basic options: 1) treat the sources as text and try to use a regular expression, 2) parse the java source into some abstract syntax tree and then extract the values - option 2 would be safer but more complex and whether option 1 would work depends on the answer to my initial questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You could compile your `.java` files and read them using [leonardosnt/java-class-tools](https://github.com/leonardosnt/java-class-tools).

You have HelloWorld.java -

```java
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
  }
}
```

Then compile -

```sh
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Then write a quick `index.js` -

```
const { JavaClassFileReader } = require('java-class-tools');

const reader = new JavaClassFileReader();
const classFile = reader.read('./HelloWorld.class');

classFile.methods.forEach(md => {
  /**
   * Method name in constant-pool.
   *
   * Points to a CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7
   */
  const nameInConstantPool = classFile.constant_pool[md.name_index];

  // To string (hacky)
  const name = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, nameInConstantPool.bytes);

  console.log(name);
});
```

Which outputs the following -

```sh
node index.js
<init>
main
```